# VueJS Unit Test "What to Test`", content of attributes?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm struggling with my first VueJS unit tests with Jest.

I understand the concept and wrote my first successful tests already but the question of "What to test" is constantly in my mind

for example: I have an element in my Component

```js
      <img v-if="!hasHoverEffect"
           :alt="model.alt"
           :src="src"
           :style="styles"
           :title="model.title"
           :class="model.shadow"
           class="img-fluid centered"/>
```

Question is: what to test here?
So far i have written 2 tests

```js
    test('renders by default', () => {
      const wrapper = factory.default();
      const img = wrapper.find('div.position-relative > img');
      expect(img.element).toBeDefined();
    });

    test('does not render if model.hovereffect is true', () => {
      const wrapper = factory.default({
        propsData: {
          model: {
            hovereffect: 'true'
          }
        }
      });
      const img = wrapper.find('div.position-relative > img');
      expect(img.element).not.toBeDefined();
    });
```

Should the next test be `test('by default alt is empty', () => {` or is that completly obsolete since this would be testing vuejs and not my component?

Answer (score 2):

For me, I ask myself the question, what are the important aspects of my component that I want to test. Usually, and I would say for your case too, this is enough:

1. Does the component render successfully
2. Does it behave has expected

It's possible to write a 100 tests checking every detail/scenario but it is not necessary (IMO). I think you cover these two points well with the tests you have written so far. Adding another just to check the alt tag is over doing it.

Comment: Agreed. It all comes down to confidence - the question to ask yourself is not what should I test, but what tests would give me the most confidence (i.e in my components etc).